# Comparision of iterative pre-order solutions

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

The most common solution to iterative pre-order tree traversal is as follows :-

```
1) Create an empty stack nodeStack and push root node to stack. 
2) Do following while nodeStack is not empty.
….a) Pop an item from stack and print it.
….b) Push right child of popped item to stack ….c) Push left child of popped item to stack
```

- Source geeksforgeeks

However I was thinking from the perspective of converting the recursive solution to iterative and came up with the following code :-

```
    private static void preorder(Node root) {
    Stack<Node> s = new Stack<Node>();

    if(root != null){
        System.out.println(root.data);
        s.push(root);
    }
    while(!s.isEmpty()){
        if(root.left != null){
            root = root.left;
            System.out.println(root.data);
            s.push(root);
        }
        else{
            Node p = s.pop();
            if(p.right != null){
                root = p.right;
                System.out.println(root.data);
                s.push(root);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering which is a better solution and why ?
If we go by the recursive solution the second implementation looks like a better solution , please correct me if I am wrong.